# Command substitution in Shell Script

Tags: shell

```
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ cat pass

hellounix
file1

#!/usr/bin
echo "Enter File Name"
read file
if [ -f $file ]
 then
    echo "File Found with a Name $file\n"
    echo "File Content as below\n"
    count=0
    val=0
    while read line
        do
        val=$("$line" | wc -c)
        echo "$line -->Containd $val Charecter"        
        count=$((count+1))
        done < $file
    echo "Total Line in File : $count"
else 
    echo "File Not Found check other file using running script"
fi
```

Output :

```
511@ubuntu:~/Unix$ sh digitmismatch.sh
Enter File Name
pass
File Found with a Name pass

File Content as below

digitmismatch.sh: 1: digitmismatch.sh: hellounix: **not found**
hellounix -->Containd 0 Charecter
digitmismatch.sh: 1: digitmismatch.sh: file1: **not found**
file1 -->Containd 0 Charecter
Total Line in File : 2
==============================================================
```

Why the value of `wc -c` is not assigned to the variable `val`?

Comment: Note the typing mistake on the first line of the script - `/usr/bin` is not a valid interpreter.  Try `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Your line is:

```
val=$("$line" | wc -c)
```

This [tries](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) to run the command given by `$line` and run the output through `wc -c`. The error message you see indicates that it's trying to run a "`hellounix`" command, as in the first line of your file. If you want to pass the value of the variable into the command instead, you can use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

```
val=$(printf '%s' "$line" | wc -c)
```

If you're using Bash, zsh, or another more powerful shell, you can also use [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
val=$(wc -c <<<"$line")
```

`<<<` performs expansion on the string `"$line"` and then provides it as the standard input of `wc -c`.

---

In this particular case, though, you can use the shell's built-in [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to get the length of the variable value without a pipeline at all:

```
val=${#line}
```

The `#` expansion expands to:

> **String Length.** The length in characters of the value of parameter shall be substituted. If parameter is '*' or '@', the result of the expansion is unspecified. If parameter is unset and set -u is in effect, the expansion shall fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
val=$("$line" | wc -c)
```

This line means "assign the output of the command `"$line" | wc -c` to the variable `val`". Let's say `$line` is holding `hellounix`, so it now looks like this:

```
val=$(hellounix | wc-c)
```

It's trying to run a command called `hellounix`, which is not found, that's why you're getting the `hellounix: not found` error.

A simple fix would be to add an `echo`, like this:

```
val=$(echo -n "$line" | wc -c)
```

This will "echo" the line to stdout, and then passes it on to `wc`. The `-n` option removes the newline character at the end of the line, because `wc` counts it. If you want to count the newline character at the end of the line, remove the `-n` option.

With `echo -n`:

```
Enter File Name
testfile
File Found with a Name testfile

File Content as below

hellounix -->Containd 9 Charecter
file1 -->Containd 5 Charecter
Total Line in File : 2
```

With only `echo`:

```
Enter File Name
testfile
File Found with a Name testfile

File Content as below

hellounix -->Containd 10 Charecter
file1 -->Containd 6 Charecter
Total Line in File : 2
```

Comment: Concepts also has been clear.. Thanks a TON.. :)